# MySQL - Order by occurrence?

Tags: mysql

I have a name and a category. When the name is entered I want to guess the category.

E.g.

**Name - Category**

Tesco - Groceries

Tesco - Groceries

Tesco - Games

What I want to get back is 1 result. However, it isn't as simple as returning 'Groceries'. Ideally I would like to only return Groceries if this has been entered at least 50% the time? Failing that I would like to only return Groceries if it has been entered at least 5 times.

I have this but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM records WHERE name='$name' AND count(category) > 5 ORDER BY count(category) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `group by` category and use a `having` clause to only return categories with 5 rows or more.

You also don't need to use `distinct` once you use `group by`.

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT category
FROM records 
WHERE name='$name' 
GROUP BY category
HAVING count(*) > 5 
ORDER BY count(*) 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to Ike's answer, if you also want to query to work if there are no items in the table that appear more than 5 times but do appear more than 50% of the times:

```
SELECT category
FROM records 
WHERE name='$name' 
GROUP BY category
HAVING count(*) >= 5 OR count(*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM records) >= 0.5
ORDER BY count(*) 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Minor pick ">= 0.5" Otherwise +1

Comment: thanks, updated it! we would actually need >= 5 as well (at least 5 items)

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    distinct(category)
from records
where
    name = '$name'
group by category
having (count(*) > 5)
order by count(*)
limit 1
```